# Jquery Unobstrustive and MVC 5 - RegEx never satisfied in jquery unobstrustive

Tags: jquery, regex, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-javascript

I am writing an MVC application and I have a requirement for a strong password. Simple enough, I set up a view model with the following property.

```
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,", ErrorMessage ="1 upper, 1 lower, 1 digit, 8 character minimum length")]
    public string PasswordEntered { get; set }
```

This works just fine when I use server validation: as long as I enter a lower an upper, a numeric and a total of 8 characters, my model is valid.

As soon as I turn on jquery unobtrusive validation, all my other fields validate without a round trip, but password stubbornly gives me my error message even if I enter a valid password like Password123.

Why does the regex fail to work? How do I correct this?

Edit:
Further research. On debugging and stepping through jquery code I see this

```
return (match && (match.index === 0) && (match[0].length === value.length));
```

So because my regex does return any match groups, jquery considers the regex as having failed. I am not sure how to get a match group to satisfy jquery...

Comment: I think the issue is in my regex even though it was working before jquery validation... looking into this now.

Comment: I simplified my regular expression and used https://regex101.com/ to validate my regex "(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])" -- note this gets rid of the length requirement. Still not validating using jquery.

Comment: It appears that because the regex doesn't give a match group that jquery doesn't recognize the result as valid. see edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a crash course in RegEx over 2 hours and going through jquery code I found that jquery requires the match group to be the same length as the input being tested. Since my original regex did not include a match group, the jquery function failed. I modified my original regex and it now works.

```
(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(.{8,}$)
```

Comment: For anyone else stuck with unobtrusive validations for passwords (probably), this is the regex you need to the length requirement to work.  I tried several other valid regex (in testers), but this is the only one that actually works at runtime